# Counting values in a JSON and converting them to number form

Tags: javascript, html, json, foreach, counting

I'm trying to figure out how to count different values in a VERY large JSON file.

Below I have included a very small portion of my 10,000+ lines JSON file. I need to count the total amount of ***"status":"booked"* and *"status":"free"*** in number form.

```
[
  {
    "eventId": 126363,
    "eventKey": "4749466",
    "objectLabelOrUuid": "uuid8083",
    "status": "booked",
    "quantity": 1,
    "ticketType": null,
    "holdTokenHash": null,
    "version": 3,
    "extraData": null
  },
  {
    "eventId": 126363,
    "eventKey": "4749466",
    "objectLabelOrUuid": "uuid11392",
    "status": "free",
    "quantity": 0,
    "ticketType": null,
    "holdTokenHash": null,
    "version": 6,
    "extraData": null
  },
  {
    "eventId": 126363,
    "eventKey": "4749466",
    "objectLabelOrUuid": "uuid8051",
    "status": "booked",
    "quantity": 1,
    "ticketType": null,
    "holdTokenHash": null,
    "version": 2,
    "extraData": null
  }
]
```

After converting them to number form i will be placing the values in an html document

```
Seats Booked: <a id="booked"></a> Seats Free: <a id="free"></a>
```

expected output:

```
Seats Booked: 2 Seats Free: 1
```

It is my understanding that i can use a foreach method to fetch the data but i am unable to count them. If you have ANY ideas or preferably **documentation** that you can link here just let me know here!

Comment: do you have only the two states of `status`?

Comment: yes, only "booked" and "free"

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: `var free=0, booked=0; for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) { var event = events[i]; free += event.status=="free"?1:0; booked += event.status=="booked"?1:0;}`

Answer (score 1):

You could count them while iterating.

For assigning the value to the elements, you could take all entries of the object and use the keys as id and assign the value to the elements.

Used techniques:

- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iterating the array,
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), for getting a single property or later for taking two values of an array,
- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for getting all keys and values of an object

```js
var data = [{ eventId: 126363, eventKey: "4749466", objectLabelOrUuid: "uuid8083", status: "booked", quantity: 1, ticketType: null, holdTokenHash: null, version: 3, extraData: null }, { eventId: 126363, eventKey: "4749466", objectLabelOrUuid: "uuid11392", status: "free", quantity: 0, ticketType: null, holdTokenHash: null, version: 6, extraData: null }, { eventId: 126363, eventKey: "4749466", objectLabelOrUuid: "uuid8051", status: "booked", quantity: 1, ticketType: null, holdTokenHash: null, version: 2, extraData: null }],
    count = { booked: 0, free: 0 };

window.onload = function() {
    data.forEach(({ status }) => count[status]++);
    Object.entries(count).forEach(([id, value]) =>
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value);
};
```

```html
Seats Booked: <a id="booked"></a> Seats Free: <a id="free"></a>
```

Comment: how would i implement this into html?

Comment: In a page load event

Comment: thank you for this, I was not aware that you could use the iterations to complete the equation!

Answer (score 0):

Give the array a name

```js
var Arr = [{ eventId: 126363, eventKey: "4749466", objectLabelOrUuid: "uuid8083", status: "booked", quantity: 1, ticketType: null, holdTokenHash: null, version: 3, extraData: null }, { eventId: 126363, eventKey: "4749466", objectLabelOrUuid: "uuid11392", status: "free", quantity: 0, ticketType: null, holdTokenHash: null, version: 6, extraData: null }, { eventId: 126363, eventKey: "4749466", objectLabelOrUuid: "uuid8051", status: "booked", quantity: 1, ticketType: null, holdTokenHash: null, version: 2, extraData: null }];
    

// and run a simple for loop to filter both values from each item

var Booked = 0,
  Free = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
  if (Arr[i].status == "booked") {
    Booked++;
  } else {
    Free++;
  }
};

// now you can put these 2 variables into html like

document.getElementById("booked").innerHTML = Booked;
document.getElementById("free").innerHTML = Free;
```

```html
Seats Booked: <a id="booked"></a> Seats Free: <a id="free"></a>
```

Comment: now, if i wanted to store my array in a file "data.json" could i import it like var Arr = $.getJSON('JsonData.json')   ?